# How to switch order of all values in a dictionary and reverse the order it?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, key-value

I do not get it done...

I have code:

```
Dictionary<string, string>[] dic = new Dictionary<string, string>[2];
dic[0].Add("10", "a");
dic[1].Add("20", "b");
```

I should output with Console.Writeline:

```
10, b 
20, a

20, a
10, b
```

That means first I should change the Values and then the key but I do not understand how to manage it. I tried the official website of microsoft but I do not come any further.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello, can you share more of your code? What have you tried and what is you current not working solution?

Comment: It seems you abuse a dictionary for something else. Is this a real reqirement or just an experience? Especially the second i don't understand because they key-value pairs don't change, just the order. But a dictionary has no order, at least you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: I am also a bit confused but I got the excercise from where I work. There is also a exercise where a dictionary is defined like that Dictionary<int, string> and at the end I should output: d, 1 although the key is an integer. That is so damn confusing. So here I look up for help with confusing excersises

Comment: You also seem to confuse a dictionary with an array of dictionaries. You are using an array but i think you need just one. Provide us at least a compiling version of the dictionary, this isn't valid syntax at all: `new Dictionary<string, string[2]`

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Oh I have forgotten the ">"

Comment: @Tofik I just removed the key-value pairs and added new ones so the output is excactly how it should be. But that solution is absurd but nothing better came to my mind sadly

Comment: @G.Don: it is still an array and the dictionaries aren't even initialized. I'm sure you don't need a dictionary-array but a single one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i should say that this requirement should not be solved with a dictionary because it's not an ordered collection. That means you shouldn't rely on the dictionaries order of the keys because it might change if you add or delete pairs and it could change with the next version of .NET.

However, if this is just an exercise. You could use a `List<T>` to access it by index:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"10", "a"}, {"20", "b"}};

List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> listDict = dict.ToList();
// 1.) switch the values, last becomes first and vice-versa
for (int i = 0; i < listDict.Count; i++)
{
    string oppositeValue = listDict[listDict.Count - 1 - i].Value;
    dict[listDict[i].Key] = oppositeValue;
}
// 2.) reverse the dictionary to "switch" the keys, this is not recommended with a dictionary, because it is not an ordered collection
dict = dict.Reverse().ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i would never come up with such an idea. Thats why I asked. Oh know I see the wrong syntax of my code. I always thought of a list instead of a dictionary because with a list it is much easier to solve that.

Comment: @G.Don: yeah, that's why i have mentioned that the dictionary isn't an ordered collection and there is a good reason why it doesn't allow to access keys or values by index. The order might not be stable even though you can enumerate it. You need to create a list (or array) from it to be able to access every key-value by index. That's what i have done above with `dict.Tolist`.

Comment: Yes, I do understand it now or rather comprehend what you did! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code wont compile

However maybe you want something like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("10", "a");
dic.Add("20", "b");

// Ouput
foreach (var key in dic.Keys)
   Console.WriteLine(key + " "+ dic[key]);

// Change 
dic["10"] = "C";
dic["20"] = "D";

// Ouput    
foreach (var key in dic.Keys)
   Console.WriteLine(key + " " + dic[key]);
```

Or maybe you just want a list

```
var list = new List<(string,string)>();
list.Add(("10", "a"));
list.Add(("20", "b"));

// order one way
foreach (var item in list.OrderBy(x => x.Item1))
   Console.WriteLine(item);

// order another
foreach (var item in list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item1))
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
10 a
20 b
10 C
20 D
(10, a)
(20, b)
(20, b)
(10, a)
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DhFZc1)